# How do I reach a folder in the appdata and delete it?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a launcher for a FiveM server, currently I'm at the "delete cache" button, the principle is that when you press it, it deletes the folders: "browser,db,dunno,priv,servers,subprocess" they are located at: \AppData\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache' but I don't know how to reach them deletes, here's the code I tried and didn't work, they do not delete themselves (I'm new in C#)

Here's the code:

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "fivem");
            string fap = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "FiveM Application Data");
            string cache = System.IO.Path.Combine(fap, "cache");
            string browser = System.IO.Path.Combine(cache, "browser");
            string db = System.IO.Path.Combine(browser, "db");
            string dunno = System.IO.Path.Combine(db, "dunno");
            string priv = System.IO.Path.Combine(dunno, "priv");
            string servers = System.IO.Path.Combine(priv, "servers");
            string Cache = System.IO.Path.Combine(servers, "subprocess");



            if (Directory.Exists(Cache))
            {
                Directory.Delete(Cache);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What you are doing seems correct (without actually ensuring each folder is at the correct path), but you are only deleting the Cache folder (which should be `cache` or `subprocessFolder` or something)

Comment: Is it a typo that you combine db from browser and so on?

Comment: @user1781290 No, I tried to combine all the files for all the deletes at the same time, I named them in order

Comment: Why do you think it “didn't work”? Did you get an error? You need to tell it to us. Note that the path you gave in your question is not the path in `Cache`; look at it in the debugger. Also that's not how to delete a folder with files in it.

Comment: @DourHighArch No, there's no error. How can i delete folders if there's file in it?

Comment: @Bakaguya - `Directory.Delete(Cache, true);`. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.delete?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_Delete_System_String_System_Boolean_): "Deletes the specified directory and, if indicated, any subdirectories and files in the directory"

Comment: @BrootsWaymb They still don't delete themselves.

Comment: You state the path as \AppData\Local\FiveM\FiveM.app\cache in the question, but you build the path \AppData\Local\FiveM\FiveM Application Data\cache ?

Comment: I think it's because "FiveM Application Data" is a file folder. I don't know how to make it work

Comment: @Bakaguya -It looks like you're misunderstanding what `Path.Combine` does. You're trying to delete a single directory at `\AppData\Local\fivem\FiveM Application Data\cache\browser\db\dunno\priv\servers\subprocess`, which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: No, I want to delete some folders that are in the cache folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that `Path.Combine` works in that way. I would modify your method like this (easier to read and maintain):

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string baseFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),"fivem", "FiveM.app");

        var folders = new string[]
        {
            "FiveM Application Data",
            "cache",
            "browser",
            "db",
            "dunno",
            "priv",
            "servers",
            "subprocess"
        };

        foreach (var folder in folders)
        {
            var toDelete = System.IO.Path.Combine(baseFolder, folder);

            if (Directory.Exists(toDelete))
            {
                Directory.Delete(toDelete, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

**if you want to delete ALL the folders inside your base folder, without choosing them by name, you can try this:**

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string baseFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),"fivem", "FiveM.app");

        foreach (var subDir in new DirectoryInfo(baseFolder).GetDirectories()) {
            subDir.Delete(true);
        }
    }
```

> Don't forget to use the `Delete` overload with `true`
>   parameter, so you can launch a recursive delete to remove all files
>   and subfolders

Comment: Hmm, it have delete all the folders in FiveM.app

Comment: glad to help, if eveything is working for you, please consider marking this answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "fivem");
            string fap = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "FiveM Application Data");
            string cache = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "cache");
            string browser = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "browser");
            string db = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "db");
            string dunno = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "dunno");
            string priv = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "priv");
            string servers = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "servers");
            string subprocess = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "subprocess");

        if (Directory.Exists(fap))
        {
            Directory.Delete(fap, true);
        }
        if (Directory.Exists(cache))
        {
            Directory.Delete(cache, true);
        }
        //repeat for all the variables

        if (Directory.Exists(subprocess))
        {
            Directory.Delete(subprocess, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably want `Directory.Delete("<path>", true);` so that it doesn't bomb if one of those directories are nonempty.